# How can I create a WIX installer that will install both to IIS6 and IIS7

Tags: iis-7, installation, wix

I'm uing various different versions of WIX trying to get an installer to be able to install to both IIS versions. I've heard that WIX doesn't natively support IIS7 so one must make a CA to provide the functionality

Does anyone have an example of how to create functionality which can do this? I've already got an installer to install the web site to IIS6 but can't attach this with an IIS7 custom action I've found.

Edit: Ahh okay I'll rephrase my question.

How would I create a UI to allow a user to choose the web site to use for IIS6 and IIS7 (i.e support all versions of IIS to query)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WiX 3.5](http://wix.sourceforge.net/downloadv35.html) supports IIS7. You should use the same elements of [IIsExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_index.htm) you normally do for IIS6. Besides, "IIS6 compatibility" prerequisite is not required any longer.